# Return multiple values in stored procedure from function - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

## sp1

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp1]            
as             
begin                        
DECLARE @od varchar(255)
EXEC @od =dbo.getFn

SELECT CMSA.A,CMSB.B, @OD
FROM CMSA INNER JOIN CMSB
GROUP BY CMSA.A, CMSB.B
end
```

## fn1

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getFn]()
returns varchar(255)
as 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @Desc1 varchar(200)
DECLARE @Desc2 varchar(200)
DECLARE c1  CURSOR FOR
SELECT CMSC.C
FROM   CMSC INNER JOIN CMSB INNER JOIN CMSC
WHERE CMSC.C = "HELLO" OR CMSC.C = "GOODBYE"
GROUP BY CMSC.C
Open c1
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @Desc1
set @Desc2=@Desc1 
CLOSE c1
deallocate c1
Return @Desc2
end
```

Just say the existing value for CMSC is HELLO and GOODBYE, and i want to display both values in stored procedure from the function. For instance,

```
CMSA.A, CMSB.B, HELLO
CMSA.A, CMSB.B, GOODBYE
```

But now, I'm only able to display a single output instead of both of the output as I mentioned above. How can I solve this?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. If you want to return multiple values from a user defined function it should return a table.

Comment: Also, your code will give you compilation error

Comment: Then, how should I return multiple values instead?
No, the code does not give me any compilation error. It only returns a single value

Comment: You will have to use a table valued function to return a table containing the two values and then do a cross join in the SP.

Comment: OK I had the table valued function to return a table containing the two values, then how should I cross join it?

Comment: To do `JOIN`, the table returned should probably have key-value pair so you can do `JOIN` with the key.

Comment: posted a sample answer. However I do see some syntax errors on the joins. So check that. Also it can be a CROSS JOIN or an INNER JOIN based on whether you have a column to reference on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Function**

The function seems erroneous as the inner joins don't have a ON statement.

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getFn]()
returns @table TABLE (value varchar(255))
as 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Desc1 varchar(200)
    DECLARE @Desc2 varchar(200)

    DECLARE c1  CURSOR FOR

    SELECT CMSC.C
    FROM   CMSC 
    INNER JOIN CMSB 
    INNER JOIN CMSC
    WHERE CMSC.C = "HELLO" OR CMSC.C = "GOODBYE"
    GROUP BY CMSC.C

    Open c1
    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @Desc1
    set @Desc2=@Desc1 
    INSERT INTO @table VALUES (@Desc2)
    CLOSE c1
    deallocate c1

    Return 
end
```

**SP**

Again the syntax of the SP is also wrong as the ON statement is missing in the INNER JOIN.

```sql
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp1]            
as             
begin                        
DECLARE @od varchar(255)
EXEC @od =dbo.getFn

SELECT CMSA.A,CMSB.B, a.Value
FROM CMSA INNER JOIN CMSB
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.getFn()) a
GROUP BY CMSA.A, CMSB.B
end
```

It might be an INNER JOIN or a CROSS JOIN depending on whether you have a field to reference on

Comment: in my function, it returns Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.getFn' because it is an incompatible object type.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL or MySQL?

Comment: SQL SERVER, nvm i solved the error and i have one more error which is "an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected" right after the  (SELECT * FROM dbo.getFn()) a query

Comment: That's what I said earlier. You need a join condition. As in (SELECT * FROM dbo.getFn()) a ON a.<somefield> = CMSB.<Somefiedl> Like wise. Else Instead of INNER JOIN put JOIN and see.